# Configuring `mod_vhost_alias` to server subdomain-based websites

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am currently in the process of setting up an Apache server that will be hosting projects built from SVN using a continuous integration server. The problem is, however, that while I've managed to configure the build server to output the revisions of a project to a directory, I'm stumped as to how to actually configure Apache using `mod_vhost_alias` to serve the different projects.

The directory structure is generated using the following pattern:

> /usr/share/Projects/r[revision]

Inside, there are two directories which I'd like to configure access via a subdomain:

> api.r[revision].testserver.local -> ./server
>
> r[revision].testserver.local -> ./web

There is already a local DNS server that serves the wildcards on `*.testserver.local` and already resolves them to the correct IP, but Apache needs to resolve the correct `DocumentRoot` for the different subdomains.

The end result I'm hoping for is that as long as the build server outputs and configures the projects inside `/usr/share/Projects/r*`, Apache will know how to resolve these subdomains without the need to write conf files and reloading configurations each time a new revision is fetched and built from SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up IP based virtual host and inside put

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "/private/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.*
RewriteRule   ^(.+)     %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^api\.r(.+)\.server\.local(.*) /Users/uros/Sites/testserver/r$1/server/$2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^r*
RewriteRule   ^(.+)     %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^r(.+)\.server\.local(.*) /Users/uros/Sites/testserver/r$1/web/$2
```

You don't need default DocumentRoot set. And don't forget that your VirtualHost need to answer on all domains, so it's better to put this host on a separate IP or include virtualhost definition first (if none found first one is used)

P.S. I know the code could be optimized, but this one works ;)

Comment: Would this work with relative paths, ie. having `r$1/server/$2` instead of the absolute path? Trying to make the setup as bulletproof as possible.